# ImportError: No module named spatial_dropout, caffe, ENet

Tags: module, neural-network, caffe, importerror, enet

When I try to train this net i got an error:

```
 ImportError: No module named spatial_dropout
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

I tried to use [this](https://github.com/TimoSaemann/ENet/tree/master/Tutorial) instruction.

Comment: Please include more information, actual code or link to the source code you are using. The question as it currently stands is completely unanswerable.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've reset your `$CAFFE_PATH`, so it's set to the absolute path of `caffe-enet`, and that you've done:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$CAFFE_PATH/python:$PYTHONPATH"
```

This fixed it for me.